# $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (x^{2^n})/(1-x^{2^{n+1}})$. Find $f(99)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (x^{2^n})/(1-x^{2^{n+1}})$. Find $f(99)$.

ATTEMPT: The following series can be re-written as $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1-x^{2^n}}\right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1+x^{2^n}}\right)$ and then expanded along.

Comment: I think you edit is wrong, I think is $\dfrac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}?$

Comment: There is something weird about the denominator i.e.the ones cancel. Can you clarify? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If this problem is $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$

Hint:Let $x^{2^n}=t$,then
$$\dfrac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}=\dfrac{t}{1-t^2}=\dfrac{1}{1-t}-\dfrac{1}{1-t^2}=\dfrac{1}{1-x^{2^n}}-\dfrac{1}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$$
so
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}-\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{2^{N+1}}}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV its not $x^{2n+1}$, its $x^{2^{n+1}}$

Comment: Hello,my answer where have $x^{2n+1}?$

Comment: @math110 I think that comment was in reply to someone else (DrMv) who misread the answer. The wrong comment was deleted.

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, I deleted the comment just moments after posting because I realized I had misread.

Comment: @math110: in the $f (x ) $ from the first line of your answer, $f (0)=0$. In the last line of your answer,  $f (0)=1$. Also, you calculated the limit assuming $|x|>1$; you might want to mention so.